# "Secure browsing" and the law

Tags: intellectual-property, privacy

With all the tools legally available to “secure” one’s connection to the internet nowadays, why aren’t government organizations like the FBI taking any legal action against the companies and people behind these applications/services, such as DuckDuckGo or Brave or Tor (although they have tried to cozy up in the past with donations)?

As great as it is to have internet “privacy” more accessible to the masses, I often feel it is too good to be true, especially in America (Of course if forced, they will certainly give up information to law enforcement agencies which can’t be helped.)

Is it a legal restriction? Constitutional right to privacy? (asking on a legal level)

*Originally asked on Information security*

Comment: Do you believe that privacy in browsing is against the law?

Comment: There are occasional attempts to outlaw encryption, even in western liberal democracies. Back in the 90s, the NSA pushed the [Clipper Chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_chip), a backdoored encryption processor (with the existence of the backdoor being touted as a benefit). It didn't catch on, and instead spurred the development of strong crypto for everyone. PGP was attacked by the US government as illegal "munitions export", but the US gov lost those cases on free speech grounds, and crypto export has since been liberalized.

Comment: Despite the noise various people make about bad behavior on the internet, the _vast_ majority of people don't engage in anything (sufficiently) nefarious to warrant such attention in the first place.  Your question basically boils down to "I think one of my neighbors down the street might be up to something, so we should all have our mail opened and read".  Politics/law aside, the technology is well enough developed now that having completely unreadable communications is a 5-minute coding job...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[switzerland](/questions/tagged/switzerland)

In a democratic country (even in the US, I suppose), there are strong restrictions for spying on someone, be it about the internet, phone calls or otherwise. I don't know whether the rumours about the FBI or CIA being able to decipher any encryption is true (I doubt it), but there are certainly laws that restrict what the CIA must not do to gather intelligence about ordinary citizens. I'm now assuming, the intelligence agency is abiding to the law.

Switzerland for instance has the very restrictive "[Federal Act on the Intelligence Service](https://www.fedlex.admin.ch/eli/cc/2017/494/en)" which declares in Art. 26ff that if somebody's postal or electronic traffic needs to be analyzed or intercepted, a prior approval by the federal court is necessary. This will only be granted if the NDB (the intelligence agency) can show that there's reason to believe that the target person is a threat to the public.

Thus, from a legal standpoint, the intelligence agency can only act when there are reasons to believe that somebody does something illegal or is about to do something illegal. If you're ending up in the focus of the CIA (or whatever agency), you're probably having a lost case anyway, unless you are a professional hacker. And thus, encrypting and other privacy measures prevent leaking personal information to third parties, which are not abiding to the law, or try to gather intelligence (such as tracking data), to which they're not officially entitled or mandated to have. Laws such as the GDPR have considerably limited what companies may do with personal data, but to control that is even harder than to control the intelligence agency. That's also why a democratic state doesn't (currently) restrict the use of privacy tools.

Answer (score 0):

There are different aspects/layers to this question.

- The **"privacy mode"** of a browser can provide two kinds of protection, it provides privacy against *other users* of a shared account e.g. on a computer at school or in a public library, and it limits but does not entirely prevent techniques which allow a site operator to track users (cookies and less obvious *'fingerprinting'* methods).
  It **does not help at all** against tracking by recording the request at the server side, or any node in between, and recording the source IP address of the request. An intelligence agency with access to some of the major [backbone nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_backbone) does not have to *fingerprint* the users with things like cookies, it has the raw data.
- A system like [Tor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(network)) is entirely different. Encrypted requests go into a Tor node, decrypted requests go out of a different Tor node, and it is hard to match the outgoing request to the end user.
  But this concept is very similar to a [virtual private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network), and there are many very good reasons to allow such VPNs. Some states do limit or ban VPNs, but this comes at a commercial cost.